# Variable passed to shell script used by awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, redhat

I have the following in my bash script (called by another script that passes the variables to it):

```
psql -qtAX -h "$1" -p "$2" -U "$3" -d "$4" -f "/script/test.sql"
```

I now want to change this to :

```
psql -qtAX -h "$1" -p "$2" -U "$3" -d "$4" -f "/script/test.sql" |
awk {print "$2"}'
```

However, this doesn't give me the right output since the variable $2 that awk is using has defaulted to the value of variable $2 (which is 5432 in the example below) that was passed to the script (instead of getting it from the piped output).

```
psql -qtAX -h testhost -p 5432 -U user -f "/script/test.sql" |
awk {print "$2"}'
```

How do I make it so that it gets the $2 value from the piped output instead?

Comment: Please, post some sample data that `psql` returns and the expected output of the awk script. (quick fix is to use quotes correctly: `... | awk '{print $2}'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  awk scripts are typically single quoted to avoid shell interpolation (variable replacement) of the awk field variables.  In your case, `$2` is meaningful to the shell so it has to be escaped with single quotes.

Try this:

```
psql -qtAX -h "$1" -p "$2" -U "$3" -d "$4" -f "/script/test.sql" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. How do I escape if I were to pattern match and print column, like so?  awk '/Time/ {print $2}'

Comment: Hmm that doesnt work unfortunately @Mark. It doesnt seem to escape properly and gets the value from $2 when I run this command `psql -qtAX -h "$1" -p "$2" -U "$3" -d "$4" -f "/script/test.sql" | awk '/Time/ {print $2}'`instead :(

Comment: Help..still struggling with this :(

Comment: Please review the output from `psql -qtAX -h "$1" -p "$2" -U "$3" -d "$4" -f "/script/test.sql"`.  See if you can post the first line or two of output.  Try breaking the command up so you can review the input to awk.   You can convince yourself that the $2 is escaped simply by reviewing `echo awk '/Time/ {print $2}'`.